# Read-only access to private GitHub repository

Tags: github, repository, readonly

I'm trying to figure out, if it is possible on GitHub to give someone read-only access to a specific private repository, allow only to see content, without the possibility of collaboration to contribute with change in the code or readme markup

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is only possible for private repositories managed by organisations.

- https://docs.github.com/en/organizations/managing-access-to-your-organizations-repositories/repository-permission-levels-for-an-organization

If your repository is an organisation one, you can visit:

- [https://github.com/`OWNER`/`REPO`/settings/access](https://github.com/%60OWNER%60/%60REPO%60/settings/access)

You can then add a collaborator and set their permission level to:

> - **Read**: Recommended for non-code contributors who want to view or discuss your project
> - **Triage**: Recommended for contributors who need to proactively manage issues and pull requests without write access
> - **Write**: Recommended for contributors who actively push to your project
> - **Maintain**: Recommended for project managers who need to manage the repository without access to sensitive or destructive actions
> - **Admin**: Recommended for people who need full access to the project, including sensitive and destructive actions like managing security or deleting a repository

Answer (score 0):

You can use read-only SSH Deploy Keys for this.

On GitHub.com, go to your repository > Settings > Deploy Keys.

GitHub's detailed documentation:
https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/managing-deploy-keys